# $\gcd(a,n)\neq 1 \implies $ there is $b$ such that $ab\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I have that

$\gcd(a,n)\neq 1$ ($a$ and $n$ are not coprime).

Then, somehow, I need to prove that exists an $b$ such that

$$ab\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$

What I did:

$$ab\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$
is the same as saying

$$ab-0 = kn,\qquad k\in \mathbb Z$$

So I need, somehow, to arrive at this equality.

Well, since $$\gcd(a,n)= d \neq 1$$
we can write $d$ as a linear combination of some integers $x$ and $y$:

$$ax + ny = d \implies ax - d = n(-y)$$

So I think I'm close to the equality I need, I just don't know what to do with $d$. I need it to be $0$, but I can't say this for every possible combination of $a$ and $n$. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $an\equiv 0\pmod{n}$, so probably you want $b\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$ such that $ab\equiv0\pmod{n}$.

Consider $d=\gcd(a,n)$; then $a=cd$ and $n=bd$ for some integers $c$ and $b$; then
$$
ab=cdb=cn\equiv0\pmod{n}
$$
and $b<n$, so $b\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing where you left off,
$$
ax-d = -ny
$$
look at the equation mod $n$,
$$
ax -d = 0
$$
$$
ax = d
$$
Remember that $d$ is a divisor of $n$, so $m = n/d$ is an integer. Multiply the equation by $m$
$$
a(mx) = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \ d\mid a,n\,\Rightarrow\, a(\overbrace{n/d}^{\large b}) = n(a/d)\equiv 0\pmod{\! n}$

Answer (score 0):

$b=n$ will do just fine, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Most simply put, if $d = \gcd(a,n)$, so that:

$a = dt,n = du$, we may take $b = u$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known fact that $\gcd(a,n) \cdot\mbox{lcm}(a,n) = an$. So write

$$a \cdot \left(\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)} \right) \equiv \mbox{lcm}(a,n) \equiv 0 \mod n$$